# Jquery mobile maps with markers and list

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, maps, microdata

I have tried to create a map with markers and a list below following [Microdata example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/load%20Microdata%20example.html) and it all works fine until I run it on iOS (simulator or iPhone) when the markers don't display, but the list does. I can't seem to work out why this problem is (have listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402698/jquery-mobile-maps-microdata-on-iphone-app)) but now i'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it...

Treid a few but getting really stuck.

The over all feel is to have a marker for the user, and some markers for some places (which I can hold remotely) and a list of all markers below, then any of these markers are clicked it shows the marker on the map.

Comment: does the simulator have internet access? sometimes this could be blocked by a firewall/proxy and cause issue

Comment: Hi Phil, yes, other parts of the app are pulling in xml feeds, and these work fine.

Comment: Did you ever found out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem sorted, we updated all libraries to there newly released version, and hey-presto!

We are now using

- Phonegap 1.2.0
- jquery.mobile-1.0
- jquery-ui-map-3.0-alpha

Hopefully this will help someone out.